# Font Awesome align center

Tags: html, font-awesome

I want to center this cheveron-down. How do you do that with icons. And  also want to resize it by making it bigger My code is below

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your own flavour of the font awesome style

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
}
```

which along with your

```
td i {
text-align:center;
}
```